# Arms fidgeting during simple walking animation

Tags: animation, rigging, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

[image: Text]
I'm trying to learn blender and this is pretty much my first couple weeks in.
I'm trying to figure out why the arms would fidget like that
I've tried messing around with graph editor but I don't get any smoother than this with all types of interpolation or manual tweaking.
I know that if I keep my arms straight throughout my animation I won't have this issue but I want to see if I can add that small detail of having the arm sway in to the body a little with elbows slightly bent.

blender file:
https://pasteall.org/blend/85153b2eade24eaeabccbee7eeb9e4d0

I'm just a game dev trying to learn blender so I don't have a lot of background.
Any help is really nice.
Thanks in advance

Comment: it has to do with how the arm is bending, make sure that it's bent a bit in Edit mode and also use the pole target to help it bend the right way. You can share your file (only the armature as we don't need the mesh) here: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Your last keyframe seems to be out of play range, it can generate the jump (because legs do the same, on hands it is just more prominent) ... if not follow @moonboots suggestions

Comment: @moonboots I've included the blender file. I'm new to blender so I'm kind of scared that removing mesh will mess things up so mesh is included.

Comment: @vklidu I was told that you should keep one frame less to avoid stuttering at the end. At least that's what most youtube recommends. Is this is not a norm practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arm can't bend correctly because you don't have any pole target for the moment. You should create 2 pole targets, it would allow you to bend the elbow correctly. Also bend a bit the elbow in *Edit* mode. And in my opinion you should stick the IK controllers to the wrist, not put it far away, but it will need to redo the keyframes for them. Also in the IK constraint change the settings: add the pole targets you have created and find the good *Pole Angle*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your generous help.
One thing that I want to ask is, this seems very tedious.. you would need to create pole target everytime? Is there some other way to quickly generate all the necessary IK and pole target? Thanks!

Comment: You have tools like Rigify or Auto-Rig which build ready to use armatures but I personally don't know these tools, plus it's better to already know how to build armatures because you may meet some problems with these tools and you need to be able to fix them